# How to synchronize access to user variables during single session?

Tags: mysql

1. I need to use user variable in `prepare` statement of mysql
   stored procedure. *(The purpose is to substitute the table name in
   `drop table` command, which is unable to be injected via `?` and
   passed via `execute using...` statement because it is not a data element)*.
2. I suppose the user variables are session-wide global variables.
3. I suppose the stored procedure accessing the user variable must be
   synchronized to protect against unwanted behaviour when it is called
   simultaneously more times within single session (which I cannot prevent).

**How to perform such synchronization?**
**Is there any chance it is performed internally by the mysql?**

It seems like mysql `get_lock()` & co. uses logic that does not help much:
`get_lock('a')` followed by `get_lock('b')` destroys state of a. Maybe I have terribly missed some point here...

For those who would ask the "what exactly would you like to do" question:

```
drop   procedure if exists drop_t_table; delimiter $$
create procedure           drop_t_table(in in_t_table_name varchar(128))
begin
    declare sql_drop varchar(256) default 'drop temporary table if exists ';

    --
    -- I would suspect sql_drop_table user variable guard should be locked here...
    --
    set @sql_drop_table = concat(sql_drop, in_t_table_name);
    --
    -- What if the procedure is preempted to another call here 
    -- and the sql_drop_table gets different table name?
    --
    prepare exe from @sql_drop_table;
    --
    -- ...and unlocked here
    --
    execute            exe;
    deallocate prepare exe;    
end$$ delimiter ;
```

Comment: To initialize variables in sql, use `:=` *(this is more better)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared *within* your stored procedure are local to the procedure. An example is `sql_drop` in your code.

Each session is, basically, single-threaded. You can't do more than one thing at a time within a session. There's no way to call a stored procedure more than once from within a particular session.

If you have more than one session you can call the same stored procedure from both of them. But, a `DROP TABLE` operation is basically *idempotent*: If you call it more than once, it has the same effect as calling it just once.  It isn't precisely idempotent: it throws an error if the table doesn't exist. But, still, dropping the same table more than once isn't any more destructive than dropping it once.

Temporary tables (a) are only visible to the session that created them, and (b) vanish when the session ends. So, going to a lot of trouble to drop them explicitly might be overkill.

So, with respect, you might be overthinking this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just careful. Are also **user variables** local to the procedure (because I wouldn't think so)?  Anyway, if an application makes "global" single mysql db connection shared accross multiple threads and these threads repeatedly call this single procedure, these calls will be automatically serialized (by the server or the connection itself) just because this is the basic nature of the connection, right?

Comment: Multiple threads calling a single MySQL connection simply won't work; the connection code isn't thread safe. I seriously doubt you have such a situation. Variables starting with @ are local to a connection, as are temporary tables.

Comment: Let's take it as hypothetical considerations. Thanks for your inputs!